# ExtJs - Basic form: Is it possible to make params key a variable?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    clientValidation: true,
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    params: {
        newStatus: 'delivered'
    },
    success: function(form, action) {
    },
        failure: function(form, action) {
        }
    }
});
```

In the code above, is it possible to set a variable as the parameter key? For example, if I had the following variable:

```
var myVar = 'newStatus';
```

and placed the variable as the param key, would the result be the same? or would it just take the variable as a string thus making the key 'myVar'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in the following way and assign it to params in the request:

```js
var formParams={};
var myVar='newStatus';
formParams[myVar]='delivered';
console.log(formParams);
```

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    clientValidation: true,
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    params: formParams,
    success: function(form, action) {
    },
        failure: function(form, action) {
        }
    }
});
```